# Decrement from an array of integers equally for all elements > 0

Tags: python, python-3.x

There are x distribution centers each with y number of products. Each day only an equal amount from all x distribution centers with remaining product can be shipped. Calculate how many days it would take to ship all product So, for an array `[3, 2, 6]` it would go:

- [3, 2, 6]
- [1, 0, 4]
- [0, 0, 3]
- [0, 0, 0]

== 3 days to ship.

Here is my attempt at the algorithm in Python.

```
import functools

def get_min_days(dist_centers):
    
    total_inventory = functools.reduce(lambda a,b: a+b, dist_centers)
    days = 0
    while total_inventory > 0:

        tmp = []
        # some number bigger than any inventory expected
        minimum_inventory = float('inf')

        for dist_center in dist_centers:
            if dist_center > 0 and dist_center < minimum_inventory:
                minimum_inventory = dist_center
    
        for dist_center in dist_centers:
            if dist_center > 0:
                tmp.append(dist_center - minimum_inventory)
            else:
                tmp.append(0)
        
        dist_centers = tmp
        total_inventory = functools.reduce(lambda a,b: a+b, dist_centers)
        days += 1
    
    print("days is ",days)

get_min_days([1,2,3])
get_min_days([2,3])
get_min_days([5,10,15])
get_min_days([5,3,15])
```

Comment: Homework, interview question, programming challenge?

Comment: Are there any guarantees that the initial inventory quantities are all non-zero?

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this problem is very, very simple (and I shouldn't give it to you, because there's more value in you finding it on your own).

Here are some nudges:

Given your current sample calls, how does the number of days relate to the number of centres?

What about if you called with `[1000, 1000, 1000]`?

Do the inventory quantities matter, or only their relation to each other?

Does the order of the list matter?

After some figuring, you should be able to replace the entire body of your function with one line. Once you do so, don't `print()` in your function; just return an integer and print from the outside.

Comment: Just for myself; It's the number of distinct integers above 0 in the array is it not?

Comment: OK, I'll ponder. That said, re "one line": although the majority seems to agree with you, I find the need to (implicitly) equate brevity with excellence strange. Who cares if you can reduce something to 1 line, if it just off-loads cognitive overhead to the guy or gal who has to read your code, years after you've moved on to greener pastures? I'd rather be guilty of verbosity myself. Perl is better at code golf at any rate.

Comment: [1000,1000,1000] == 1. Am I missing something?

Comment: It's not the one line on its own that's the important part (and overall I agree with you that brevity isn't always a good goal unto itself), but this problem really does call for a much lower complexity solution.

Answer (score 0):

The end of this is going to be that Reinderien is correct and that there is a much more efficient algorithm to find the number of days.  But in the meantime, there are several items that should be noted in your approach:

- Python doesn't have all that many [builtin functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html).  It would be good to review those.  The first one that jumped out at me is:
- `functools.reduce(lambda a,b: a+b, dist_centers)` should become `sum(dist_centers)` (and we can remove the `import`).
- There's also a `min` function.  `min(dist_centers)` won't quite work though, because it would get the 0 entries.  We can use two approaches: (1) filter out the 0 entries before taking the min, or (2) ignore the 0 entries while finding the min.  I'll start with (2) and come back to (1) later.  (2) can be done by: `min( d for d in dist_centers if d>0 )`.
- That `min` code I just used involves a "generator expression".  There are also "list", "dict", and "set" expressions.  The general idea is that instead of creating an empty thing and then filling it one piece at a time, you can create and fill the thing all at once.  For example, instead of using `tmp`, we can recreate `dist_centers` with a list expression: `[ d-minimum_inventory if d>minimum_inventory else 0 for d in dist_centers ]`.  You can read expressions fairly quickly, and they'll really simplify your code.
- A non-zero value is considered True, so we don't need `thing>0` in our comparisons and can just use `thing`.
- We don't really use the `total_inventory`, other than to check that we should keep looping.  But to know if we should keep looping, the only thing to figure out is if any of the centers still have product to ship.  And it turns out Python has a builtin `any` function for exactly this case (and since we just need a non-zero value, we can just say `any(dist_centers)`).  Now we no longer need the `total_inventory` variable.
- Reinderien mentioned not printing within the function.  The general idea is that functions should focus on doing one thing, which is finding the number of days.  That way, if you want to do something else with the number of days, you can do so without needing to rewrite the function.  (Speaking of printing, `print("days is ",days)` gives two spaces between "is" and `days`, which is probably not intended.)
- I've added a `__name__=='__main__'` guard.  It's not really necessary for a one-off script, but for general programing this allows you to tell whether you're importing your script into a larger program, or just using the script on its own.
- Type hints can be a nice addition to code without much trouble, so lets add them in.

This leaves your approach looking like:

```python
def get_min_days(dist_centers:list[int]) -> int:
    days:int = 0
    while any(dist_centers):
        minimum_inventory = min( d for d in dist_centers if d )
        dist_centers = [ d-minimum_inventory if d>minimum_inventory else 0 for d in dist_centers ]
        days += 1
    return days

if ( __name__ == '__main__' ):
    print("days is",get_min_days([1,2,3]))
    print("days is",get_min_days([2,3]))
    print("days is",get_min_days([5,10,15]))
    print("days is",get_min_days([5,3,15]))
```

I mentioned before the idea of filtering out the 0 values as they happen.  Using the idea that a non-empty list is also Truthy, this lets us have:

```python
    while dist_centers:
        minimum_inventory = min(dist_centers)
        dist_centers = [ d-minimum_inventory for d in dist_centers if d>minimum_inventory ]
```

The only danger is if a center started out with 0 product, then the first day would be lost with producing 0 before those get filtered out.  If that's a possibility, then we should start with `dist_centers=filter(None,dist_centers)`.  The biggest downside of this approach is that we can no longer track how much a particular center is producing each day, because we keep changing which center goes with which index.

We've gotten things down to a 7 line function with a runtime that is quadratic in the number of distribution centers.  But by thinking of things in a different way, you can find a 1 line function with a linear runtime.  So one possible answer is "you should delete everything and write that one line".  On the other hand, most of my bulleted points will apply to any script you write, so it's still worthwhile to read through (in my opinion).

Comment: I find super long list comprehensions hard to read, but still, this is food for thought.

Comment: I couldn't get the second block of code to do the right thing, is it supposed to stand alone?

Comment: The second block replaces those lines from the first block.